# loginaction says "please re-type password

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, stripe-payments

This is my viecontroller -

```
 import UIKit
 import FirebaseFirestore
 import FirebaseAuth
 import Stripe
 import FirebaseFunctions

class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {
var paymentContext = STPPaymentContext()

@IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordConfirm: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var login: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var loginpassword: UITextField!
@IBAction func signUpAction(_ sender: Any) {
    if password.text != passwordConfirm.text {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Password Incorrect", message: "Please re-type password", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else{
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email.text!, password: password.text!){ [self]
            (user, error) in if error == nil {
                // 
                Functions.functions().httpsCallable("createStripeUser").call(["email": email.text ?? ""]) {
                    (result, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
                        return
                    }
                    self.dismiss(animated: true)
                }
            }
            else{
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
@IBAction func loginAction(_ sender: Any) {
      
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email.text!, password: password.text!) { (user, error) in
   if error == nil{
     self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginToHome", sender: self)
                  }
    else{
     let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
     let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                    
      alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
      self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
         }
     }
        
    }
  }
```

The "signUpAction" action works fine but the "loginAction" does not. It says "re-type password whether the user is registered or not as shown below:-
[image]

The firebase and stripe customer is authenticated as shown in the figures below:-

[image]

[image]

What am a I doing wrong ?

Comment: What text string have you entered in those fields?

Comment: "se@s.com" as username and password is "password", irrespective of what a I enter, it says re-type password.